# How to measure the rendering time of the frame buffer in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I want to measure the lcd rendering time in the Linux lcd driver in kernel space.
Please suggest standard methods to measure the rendering time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user do_gettimefoday function to get the time value.

`struct timeval time;`

`unsigned long local_time;`

`do_gettimeofday(&time);`
`local_time = (u32)(time.tv_sec - (sys_tz.tz_minuteswest * 60));`
`rtc_time_to_tm(local_time, &tm);`

`printk(" @ (%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d)\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);`